# Importing moment-range into Angular 4.x application (ES6) - no compatible call signatures error?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, momentjs

I am trying to import the moment-range package into my Angular 4.x application the official documentation shows this :-

```
import Moment from 'moment';
import { extendMoment } from 'moment-range';
const moment = extendMoment(Moment);
```

However in my application moment has been added by the following method :

```
import * as Moment from 'moment';
```

So I decided to use the same method to try and get moment-range to work

```
import * as Moment from 'moment';
import * as MomentRange from 'moment-range';
const moment = MomentRange(Moment);
```

However I am getting the following typescript error - can anyone suggest how I fix this?

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. 
Type 'typeof "/node_modules/moment-range/dist/moment-range"' 
has no compatible call signatures.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this on github and it worked for me - hope it helps others

```
import * as moment from 'moment';
import { extendMoment } from 'moment-range';

const { range } = extendMoment(moment);

const timeRange = range(moment.utc([2015, 0, 1]), moment.utc([2015, 5, 1]));
```